# Gorm joinTable columns are not primary

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm creating a 2 domain objects with join table:

```
class DeliveryMethod {

    List<PaymentMethod> paymentMethods = new ArrayList<PaymentMethod>()
    static hasMany = [paymentMethods: PaymentMethod];
    static constraints = {
    }
    static mapping = {
    }
}

class PaymentMethod {
    String name;
    static constraints = {

    }
    static mapping = {
    }
}
```

The join table is created, but the problem is that join columns are not primary keys in it and they're nullable, and only one of them is foreign key. Is this a bug or it can be configured somehow?

[image]

Comment: Declaring paymentMethods as `List` you're saying that they're not unique in one `DeliveryMethod`. Is really what you want or the payment method should be unique?

Comment: I don't need uniquness, I need them to be primary and foreign. Such behaviour was when I used Java + Spring + Hibernate. I wonder why is it differs in gorm(as it uses same technologies underneath)

Comment: OK, I changed List to Set and now they're both foreign, but none of them is primary

Comment: Are you using migrations or standard `dbCreate="create-drop"`?

Comment: I'm using dbCreate = "update"